# Any recommendations for Scalable front end design methodologies (Spring Framework)

Tags: java, spring, user-interface, frontend, user-experience

I have some questions from UI folks @java technology

I have recently switched from php to java domain. Though I have good experience in front end theming work with CMS application driven by php.

Since, know i am very new to spring framework, and have developed an understanding with jsp files for the UI aspect.

If you may recommend, assist me or give suggestions... what best design ui practices can be followed to make the design live as consistent looking organism in the enterprise level application.

right now, bootstrap is css framework of choice...and is well adopted into application.

Sharing some details, though I find it very challenging to teach the java developers, the aspect of ui design... apart from their primary task of coding, building the logic from product owner requirements and UI inputs from wireframe screen...

as they are not visually inclined to 'pixel' based aesthetics... i have found interface does not come out well at places...and do not look very polished

and since there is resource crunch of good UI/UX foks who can solve their problems and apart from coding the best interaction in the application, new features ...blah etc.

Though, have started to train them slowly, repeatedly and steadily...on teaching them on how to reuse your css code, write efficient styles and to attain the level of well aligned and well thought placed pixels on screen/viewport.

What best or any training module i can bring on, so that they become self sufficient... for e.g. have been done also

http://slid.es/gauravmishr/introduction-to-css-for-jsp-developers

Will like to know your recommendation and thoughts, so that design scalability can be achieved. 
Over to java ui/ux gurus :- )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you should give [Asual's Summer](http://www.asual.com/summer/) a try. It is a presentation layer library for Spring MVC. It allows you to reference resources from jars and thus makes modularization really easy. Most importantly for me, you write simple html5 with some custom tags and el expressions instead of JSPs. It also has support for resource caching and compression. Finally, you can prepare html templates to include in your views, thus increasing core reusability. I have used it extensively with twitter bootstrap and it works great.